# Setting the TabIndex property in WinForms

Tags: winforms

Back in the ancient days in VB6, two different controls could not have the same TabIndex. If I tried to assign a control with the same index as another control, the other control's index would be scooted up sequentially in the tab order.

Now in .NET, I see 2 controls have the same index.

How can this make sense?

Is there a utility to easily set the sequence without having to iterate through the property grid?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the designer doesn't 'fix' the TabIndex you set.  There's an interactive tool to set them.  Use View + Tab Order and click the controls in the order you want to tab them.

Comment: One learns something new everyday, never knew this feature even exists +1!